# fast algorithm for merging overlapping intervals

Tags: javascript, algorithm, intervals

I am trying to program a fast enough algorithm to merge intervals with values.

For example, there are 3 intervals (Including from and to):

1. `{from:1, to: 3, amount: 1}`
2. `{from:5, to: 7, amount: 1}`
3. `{from:2, to: 6, amount: 1}`

Result:

1. `{from:1, to: 1, amount: 1}`
2. `{from:2, to: 3, amount: 2}`
3. `{from:4, to: 4, amount: 1}`
4. `{from:5, to: 6, amount: 2}`
5. `{from:7, to: 7,amount: 1}`

When the number of intervals reaches 5000, then the calculations in my algorithm can take about one minute. (in the case when each new interval on the merge overlaps a large number of others).
Maybe someone can advise some already known algorithm that is suitable for this task, or maybe he has already encountered a similar problem and will share his solution?

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcHiY.png)
  [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jojSu.png)

```
       function mergeingIntervals(intervals: IInterval[]): IInterval[] {
            //sort by length
            intervals.sort((a, b) => b.to - b.from - a.to + a.from);
            const result = [intervals[0]];
            intervals.forEach(interval => addInterval(result, interval));
            result.sort((a, b) => a.from - b.from);

            return result;
        }

        function addInterval(result: IInterval[], interval: IInterval): void {
            const firstIntersectionIndex = result.findIndex(row =>
                row.from >= interval.from && row.to <= interval.to ||
                row.from >= interval.from && row.from <= interval.to ||
                row.from <= interval.from && row.to >= interval.to ||
                row.to >= interval.from && row.to <= interval.to,
            );

            if (firstIntersectionIndex === -1) {
                const indexToInsertInto = result.findIndex(row => row.from > interval.to);
                if (indexToInsertInto !== -1) {
                    result.splice(indexToInsertInto, 0, interval);
                } else {
                    result.unshift(interval);
                }
            } else {
                const valueToMergeInto = result[firstIntersectionIndex];
                if (valueToMergeInto.from <= interval.from && valueToMergeInto.to >= interval.to) {
                    const newIntervals: IInterval[] = [];
                    if (valueToMergeInto.from !== interval.from) {
                        newIntervals.push({
                            from: valueToMergeInto.from,
                            to: subtractHour(interval.from),
                            value: valueToMergeInto.value,
                        });
                    }
                    newIntervals.push({
                        from: interval.from,
                        to: interval.to,
                        value: interval.value + valueToMergeInto.value,
                    });
                    if (valueToMergeInto.to !== interval.to) {
                        newIntervals.push({
                            from: addHour(interval.to),
                            to: valueToMergeInto.to,
                            value: valueToMergeInto.value,
                        });
                    }
                    result.splice(firstIntersectionIndex, 1, ...newIntervals);
                } else {
                    let count = 1;
                    result.slice(firstIntersectionIndex).forEach(sumValue => {
                        if (sumValue.to <= interval.to) {
                            count++;
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    if (count < 5) {
                        result.splice(firstIntersectionIndex, 1);
                        const newIntervals: IInterval[] = [];
                        if (interval.from < valueToMergeInto.from) {
                            newIntervals.push({
                                from: interval.from,
                                to: subtractHour(valueToMergeInto.from),
                                value: interval.value,
                            }, {
                                from: valueToMergeInto.from,
                                to: Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                value: valueToMergeInto.value + interval.value,
                            });
                            if (interval.to !== valueToMergeInto.to) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: addHour(Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to)),
                                    to: Math.max(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                    value: valueToMergeInto.to < interval.to ? interval.value : valueToMergeInto.value,
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (interval.from !== valueToMergeInto.from) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: valueToMergeInto.from,
                                    to: subtractHour(interval.from),
                                    value: valueToMergeInto.value,
                                });
                            }
                            newIntervals.push({
                                from: interval.from,
                                to: Math.min(interval.to, valueToMergeInto.to),
                                value: interval.value + valueToMergeInto.value,
                            });
                            if (interval.to !== valueToMergeInto.to) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: addHour(Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to)),
                                    to: Math.max(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                    value: valueToMergeInto.to < interval.to ? interval.value : valueToMergeInto.value,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        newIntervals.forEach(period => addInterval(result, period));
                    } else {
                        const newIntervals: IInterval[] = [];
                        if (interval.from < valueToMergeInto.from) {
                            newIntervals.push({
                                from: interval.from,
                                to: subtractHour(valueToMergeInto.from),
                                value: interval.value,
                            }, {
                                from: valueToMergeInto.from,
                                to: Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                value: interval.value,
                            });
                            if (interval.to !== valueToMergeInto.to) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: addHour(Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to)),
                                    to: Math.max(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                    value: valueToMergeInto.to < interval.to ? interval.value : 0,
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (interval.from !== valueToMergeInto.from) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: valueToMergeInto.from,
                                    to: subtractHour(interval.from),
                                    value: 0,
                                });
                            }
                            newIntervals.push({
                                from: interval.from,
                                to: Math.min(interval.to, valueToMergeInto.to),
                                value: interval.value,
                            });
                            if (interval.to !== valueToMergeInto.to) {
                                newIntervals.push({
                                    from: addHour(Math.min(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to)),
                                    to: Math.max(valueToMergeInto.to, interval.to),
                                    value: valueToMergeInto.to < interval.to ? interval.value : 0,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        const valuesToMergeIntoArray = result.splice(firstIntersectionIndex, count, ...newIntervals);
                        valuesToMergeIntoArray.forEach(period => addInterval(interval, period));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting from your input to your output, you'll need to explain what you're actually doing. (Preferably, show your current solution, even if it's not ideal/fully functional)

Comment: I added a picture that explains the principle of merging

Comment: The image doesn't really tell us anything, we need to see the process of getting between the input and the output, not just a graphical version of the same in/out data. Since you've already got working code, please include it here in a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @greatstone My first step would be to sort the input data according to start times and end times.

Comment: Is your from/to values restricted to integers or can they be any number (ie 4.55)?

Comment: I added the code of my implementation for clarity

Comment: @DougCoburn There are only integers.

Comment: @DBS I added the code

Comment: What's more important, speed of adding 1 interval to an existing list of 5000 clean merged intervals or speed of sorting out a list of 5000 unmerged intervals into a new clean set of merged intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create entries for amount changes that happen on single points (in time), so you would actually double the number of entries that your input has. Then sort that by that key. Make the keys unique in that sorted array, aggregating the amount changes that apply to the same key. Finally build the output from that array.

```js
function mergedIntervals(intervals) {
    let arr = [];
    // Store separate entries for "from" and for "to".
    for (let {from, to, amount} of data) {
        arr.push({ key: from, amountChange:  amount, countChange:  1});
        arr.push({ key: to+1, amountChange: -amount, countChange: -1});
    }
    // sort by key
    arr.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key);
    // aggregate by key
    let last = {};
    let unique = [];
    let count = 0;
    let amount = 0;
    for (let {key, amountChange, countChange } of arr) {
        amount += amountChange
        count += countChange;
        if (key === last.key) {
            last.amount = amount;
            last.count = count;
        } else {
            unique.push(last = { key, amount, count });
        }
    }
    // generate result
    let result = [];
    last = null;
    for (let { key, amount, count } of unique) {
        if (last) last.to = key - 1;
        if (!count) {
            last = null;
        } else if (!last || last.amount !== amount) {
            result.push(last = { from: key, to: null, amount });
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// example run
let data = [ 
    {from: -5, to: 10, amount:  0}, // negative from
    {from: -4, to:  0, amount:  1}, // overlapping
    {from:  1, to:  2, amount:  2}, // adjacent to previous
    {from:  0, to:  6, amount: -5}, // negative amount
    // no coverage between 11 and 14
    {from: 15, to: 20, amount:  3}, // after gap
    {from: 18, to: 25, amount:  4}, // partly overlapping
];
console.log(mergedIntervals(data));
```

Comment: Thank you, @NinaScholz. That this comes from you, makes me proud :-)

Comment: i made a kind of shorter version ... :-)

Comment: @trincot, Unfortunately, your example doesn't work correctly at intervals with an `amount=0`

Comment: @greatstone, do you have an example and the wanted result of it? please edit the question for it.

Comment: @greatstone, please add an example with zero amount and the wanted result of it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Run the code above, I adjusted it and added an example with a zero interval

Comment: @NinaScholz Are you looking at an example from a @trinсot? I made changes there.

Comment: @NinaScholz oh, sorry. It was rejected

Comment: @greatstone, i have seen the edit propsal. my approach works without changes with zero attributes.

Comment: @NinaScholz https://codepen.io/greatstone/pen/VwLYZLQ?editors=1111 here you can find an example

Comment: @greatstone, I understood from your question that `amount` is to be *added* to whatever is actual in that interval. Since your desired output does not specify 0 from -Infinity to +Infinity, it was my understanding that 0 represented "no change", and so no explicit 0 needs to be included in the output. Please explain why then you don't want 0 in the complete integer range.

Comment: @trincot If there is an interval with zero amount at the input, and when merging with other intervals, a fragment with a zero amount remains, then it should be left in the output intervals. Which I did by redoing your example. Btw, thanks for the idea, your implementation is many times faster than mine.

Comment: I see. I know you accepted the answer, but I still updated it according to your requirement. The sample input now includes a gap with no coverage, and some negative values for either from/to or amount.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a kind of short version of [tricot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098855/1447675) which rely on the sorted index like keys of arrays in Javascript and a combined sigle value for a certain time stamp.

The result is made of sorted entries of the object and checks if either is a last object or if the amount is not zero (opposit as for the last entry) a new object is pushed to the result set.

```js
function mergedIntervals(intervals) {
    let values = {},
        last,
        result = [],
        amount = 0;

    for (let { from, to, amount } of intervals) {
        values[from] = (values[from] || 0) + amount;
        values[to + 1] = (values[to] || 0) - amount;
    }

    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(values)) {
        amount += v;
        if (last) {
            last.to = k - 1;
            if (amount === last.amount) continue;
        }
        result.push(last = { from: +k, to: null, amount });
    }
    result.pop();
    return result;
}

let data = [{ from: 1, to: 7, amount: 0 }, { from: 1, to: 2, amount: 1 }, { from: 3, to: 4, amount: 0 }, { from: 6, to: 7, amount: 1 }];

console.log(mergedIntervals(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is nice too. Just one limitation: it can only work for from/to in the "array index" range [0..2^32), so if ever values outside that range are needed (negative or integers >= 2^32), then another solution is needed.